# Windows 8 stuck installing update

Tags: windows, windows-8, updates, format

I just restarted my laptop to finish installing a Windows update and now it is stuck on please wait.

I have tried a system restore but there is only one restore point in the list and it does not work for some reason...

I also tried to do a refresh but it asks me for media. I plug in the usb I used to install windows 8 a while and go and says that the media failed to load.

I'm kind of stuck on options now. I can't boot and I can't restore and it seems I cant format either!

Is there anything anything else I can do to get things going?!

I'm running Windows 8 on a dell xps 14 ultrabook. Win 8 is installed on an msata drive and booting using EFi.

Comment: I had such a problem SFC /scannow revealed disc corruption on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot from an Win8 setup DVD/USB thumb drive, to the repair options and select Command Prompt. Now run this command:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 8)

This reverts all pending operation of Windows Update. Are you now able to boot?

Answer (score 0):

I had already formatted the machine, so I could not try the answers. If anyone decides to format, it has to be done manually in system recovery mode.

Re-installing Windows 8 in UEFI was also a pain since the bootloader kept trying to find the old installation and failed to load from USB.

After disabling secure boot and deleting all boot keys from BIOS it finally allowed me to re-install windows.

Answer (score 0):

The install may be stalling because while your equipment may be compatible your Bios may not be. check with manufacturer for a compatible bios update.