# My Windows 8 desktop is stuck on updating

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

My HP Windows 8 desktop has been stuck on updates for hours and I don't know what to do. It's been displaying the message, "Updating 11 of 11..." For hours but can't seem to complete the operation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Running a manual check for updates will work, it worked for me

What you have to do is to [install the  KB2771431](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771431) first  then run a manual check for the other Windows 8 updates and install them, it will work fine.

The other solution is to restore the system to a point and then install the updates manually

I found [this awesome link](http://www.programmerfish.com/windows-8-freezes-during-installation-of-updatessolved/) which explains the solutions to this Windows 8 Stall problem

Answer (score 1):

Here are two similar questions:
[Windows 8 stuck installing update](https://superuser.com/questions/520679/windows-8-stuck-installing-update) and 
[How to cancel Windows Update?](https://superuser.com/questions/690337/how-to-cancel-windows-update/719803#719803) .
In the last one I've written an answer.

Hopefully I'm not violating user policy by reposting my answer here, but not many people seem to have found the Q I originally answered.

---

Here is an alternative way, without the commandline.

First, when accessing the update options through Metro by doing *mouse to upper right corner->Settings->Change computer settings->Update/Restore* there is not even an "abort"-button to press.

The Windows Update options have to be accessed through the classic desktop Control Panel, where you promptly discover that even though you are an user with Administrator priviligies you can't press the abort button. My guess is that this is a bug where MS forgot to add whatever is needed for that small shield to be added to the button and check user privileges .

Instead, go to *Control Panel->Services* and scroll down to *Windows Update* service. Right-click and press Restart, and hopefully you can now select/deselect which updates to install.

Comment: That's because developers stopped saying "Abort" back in the '90s. It's "Cancel".

Answer (score 0):

If Update Freezes then you can do one out of the following as prescribed by Microsoft

**Method 1: Run the scan again**

> If the scan freezes and doesn't complete when Windows Update is
>   scanning for updates, try to run the scan again. If you still can't
>   scan for updates successfully, go to method 2.

**Method 2: Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter**

If Windows Update freezes during download, use the following method. If this method doesn't resolve your issue, go to method 3.

[Fix it for me](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700567)

**Method 3: Perform a System Restore**

[image: Perform a system restore]

**Method 4: Refresh your PC**

[image: Refresh your PC]

NOTE : For more of this, please visit this [Link.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2700567)